# How to use So Inversion

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context, inversion

I came across "so" inversion without "that" do you ratify this clause and supply more examples ?

The attitudes towards the use of insect in animal feed and resulting livestock products are generally favourable, *so* has recent scientific research shown.

X : I like pop-music.
Y : So do I / Me, too.

If like this, please demystify to differetiate between "Me, too" and "So do I".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your first example, I would say (and it is more natural to say):
The attitudes towards the use of insect in animal feed and resulting livestock products are generally favourable, *as* recent scientific research *has* shown.

In the second example, both are ok, but *So do I* sounds a bit more emphatic.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Would you mind adding some sources to your answer?

Comment: Do I mean that first and second clause is the same semantically ?  (So do I .., so has recent scientific research shown